# create msbuild package for mvc project using command prompt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, command-prompt

Can anyone give an msbuild command to create build package from .sln?
My Project is an asp.net mvc project.

I want to create a build folder which contains dlls, pages, fonts and all such folders. i dont want to use visual studio.

Tried the below but fails

```
msbuild C:\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test
```

Please suggest!

Thanks

Comment: What is the error messgae it fails with?

Comment: I am using this command : MSBuild "C:\Code\MyCode.sln"  /P:Configuration=Debug;PackageLocation="C:\build\Package.zip"

Comment: I am using this command : 'MSBuild "C:\Code\MyCode.sln"  /P:Configuration=Debug;PackageLocation="C:\build\Package.zip" ' and getting error as mentioned : **aspconfig it is an error to use a section registered as allowdefinition='machinetoapplication'**